# Phoenix session debugging/configuration

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am having trouble with even the most basic of session operations in Phoenix. For example, if I generate the stock Phoenix (1.4) app, and the only change I make is to page_controller.ex, the index action of which now looks like:

```
 def index(conn, _params) do
   put_session(conn, :franch, "foo")
   text(conn, "session is: #{get_session(conn, :franch)}")
 end
```

when I start the server and navigate to that page, I see:

```
session is:
```

Is there some additional configuration that I need to do in order to be able to store values in the session? The stock app fetches the session in the browser pipeline so I was assuming there's no more to do, but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: `conn` is immutable. Try `conn = put_session(conn, :franch, "foo")`

Comment: Duh. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Elixir is a functional programming language, variables are immutable. Which means that you are guaranteed to have the same value before and after a method call unless you reassign the variable:

```
foo = "Hello"
AnyModule.anyMethod(foo) 
foo # You are guaranteed that foo still points to the value "Hello"
```

The only way to get the variable foo to reference some value other than what is currently assigned to it, is to reassign it:

```
foo = "Hello"
foo = MyModule.addThere(foo)
foo # "Hello There"
```

So, `put_session(conn, key, value)` can not modify the passed in parameter `conn` it instead returns a new Plug.Conn which is materially the same as the old one, except with the new key/value pair.

To get the text to display correctly you need to assign conn to the output of the method

```
 conn = put_session(conn, key, value)
```